# posting an unanswered Math.SE question on MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, math-stackexchange

I have a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716247/local-cohomology-mayer-vietoris-sequence) on Math.SE which hasn't received any responses. Is it alright to repost it to MathOverflow? If so, how long should I wait before doing so?

Comment: It all depends on what the question is. Why don't you link to it?

Comment: @ToddTrimble added.

Comment: Does $\Gamma_I(M)$ mean $H_I^0(M)$? If not, the notation should probably be explained.

Comment: @ToddTrimble yes, it does.

Comment: If you post it here, be sure to indicate both here and there that the question has been posted in both sites (add links); if you get an answer in one, you should also indicate this fact in the other site (to prevent duplication of efforts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that no one has come out and said it is inappropriate for MathOverflow probably means the community thinks it's alright for MO. Maybe give it another day before posting here. It might be good to refer to this meta discussion; I'd be happy to give it a vote of support (perhaps it's not "research-level", but it's the kind of graduate-level question that would have been happily entertained at various points in the history of MO).

Comment: I would say: wait a week from posting in one before posting in the other.